# Delete a string in javascript, without leaving an empty space?

Tags: javascript, replace

I've seen multiple instance of that kind of question, but not the one I'm looking for specifically... (I just hope I'm not hopelessly blind ! :P)

Let's consider this code:

```
var oneString = "This is a string";
document.write(oneString.replace("is", ""));
```

I would have assumed that the output would have been:

```
This a string.
```

But this is the output I'm getting:

```
This a  string
```

It's like replace() think that the second argument sent is " " and not ""... What would be the proper manner then to strip the string of a given string, without having extra spaces floating in my output ?

Comment: Keep in mind that your expected output is actually: `Th is a string`. It will only replace once, and the first `is` it finds.

Comment: I didn't knew about that! I'll keep that in mind! Good thing, this was just for the example, on the real side, the seek after string is (and always will be) unique !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually getting "is" replaced with an empty string, it's the space *before* and *after* the "is" you replace that stay around as the two spaces you see. Try;

```
oneString.replace("is ", "")
```

Comment: Oh my god. I feel SO stupid right now, this is indeed the case! I need to get some sleep... Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
var aString = "This is a string";
var find = "is";    // or 'This' or 'string'
aString = aString.replace(new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + find + "(\\s+|$)", "g"), "$1");
console.log(oneString);
```

The only case where this isn't perfect is when you replace the *last* word in the sentence. It will leave one space at the end, but I suppose you could check for that.

The `g` modifier is to make the `replace` replace all instances, and not just the first one.

Add the `i` modifier to make it case insensitive.

If you also want this to work on strings like:

`"This has a comma, in it"`

Change the regexp to:

```
var find = "comma";
new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + find + "(\\s+|$|,)", "g")
```

Comment: (I need one more reputation to give vote up! But you're absolutely right, as Joachim is too !)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not getting "This  a string"?

I think you should replace "is " with  "" to get your desired output. There is a space before as well as after the word.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the original string - "This_is_a_string" (I replaced spaces with underscores).  When you remove "is", you don't touch either of the surrounding spaces, so both end up in the output.  What you need to do is `oneString.replace("is","").replace(/ +/," ")` -- get rid of "is" and then eliminate any double spaces.  If you want to keep some double spaces, try `oneString.replace(" is","")` instead, though you will run into issues if the string starts with is (eg "is it safe?").

The best answer might be something like `oneString.replace(/is ?/,"") to match is possibly followed by a space or`oneString.replace(/ ?is ?/," ") to match is possibly surrounded by spaces, and replace all of them with one space.

Comment: This was indeed a problem of the surrounding spaces! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include any spaces in your pattern. When I try your code in Chrome I get:

```
> "This is a string".replace("is","")
  "Th is a string"
```

One way to accomplish what you're trying would be to use a regexp instead:

```
> "This is a string".replace(/is\s/,"")
  "This a string"
```